# What did President Trump mean by "the record is in"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

US president Donald Trump in his Jerusalem-is-the-capital-of-Israel address said:

> In 1995 Congress adopted the Jerusalem Embassy Act urging the federal government to relocate the American embassy to Jerusalem and to recognize that that city, and so importantly, is Israel's capital. This act passed Congress by an overwhelming bipartisan majority, and was reafirmed by unanimous vote of the Senate, only six months ago. Yet for over 20 years, every previous American president has exercised the law's waiver, refusing to move the US embassy to Jerusalem, or to recognize Jerusalem as Israel's capital city. Presidents issued these waivers under the belief that delaying recognition of Jerusalem would advance the cause of peace. Some say they lacked courage, but they made their best judgement based on facts as they understood them at the time. **Nevertheless**, **the** **record** **is** **in**. After more than two decades of waivers, we are no closer to a lasting peace agreement between Israel and the palestinians. It would be folly to assume that repeating the exact same formula, would now produce a different or better result.

**Edit**

[Youtube link to the address](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=E3-i9_gUL5A)

I transcribed the video myself, but here's an online [transctipt on The US government White House website](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/statement-president-trump-jerusalem/)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's supposed to mean "the data is in" (in the sense that data collectively becomes a record), but it's not very good. All I can say is that whether or not you like Donald Trump, it's probably not a good idea to try to learn to speak English by listening to him. "The record is in" is not idiomatic.

When you say that something "is in," it typically means it has arrived, and you have a conclusion. For example, when you conduct a study, you set an end date, and when the study is over, you might say "the data is in" and you are ready to present your conclusion.

I believe that is what Trump's speech writers meant to say, here. However, I dislike "record" being used in this context. Unlike data, where we often sample it and base a conclusion upon the sample, a "record" is the recording of *all* knowledge on a subject. Unless something is officially dead or over, the record can never be complete. For example, the "historical record" can never "come in" until the world ends.

Answer (score 0):

So what's the question here?  Are you asking us what "the record is in" means?  If that should be the case, I'm going to point to the context clues.  It means that after Trump had looked at the record of everything, he came to the conclusion that nothing has changed in that area of the world; there is always going to be fighting and war, so he's just not going to waive this law anymore; he's going to enforce it now.

"The record is in" is similar to saying "the verdict is in" or "a decision has been made".  I disagree with joiedevivre in the sense that I do not think that Trump himself said this; I think, in the words of Donald Trump, this is an article written by the biased news of CNN!  I could be wrong, however.  I do agree with joiedevivre that you shouldn't try to learn good English by listening to Donald Trump as his grammar isn't the best.  Where did you find this?

Comment: https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/statement-president-trump-jerusalem/

Comment: It must be fake news lol. I'm joking, joiedevivre. It is a press release, but is it in Donald Trump's own words? Did he write this or say this? Even if he said this, it was probably written by one of his lackeys.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Donald Trump's staff controls whitehouse.gov, and according to that site, those are his words. Do I think someone else wrote them? Yes. Both because presidents usually have speech writers and because, with the exception of this odd sentence, this sounds much more coherent than his impromptu speaking.

Comment: I concur, joiedevivre. I was merely joking around with you. I also agree that one should not try to learn English by listening to Trump speak.

Comment: @Nick, As a muslim, I may have a few reasons to not like him, but I really don't hate him. After all, he is serving the interests of his country and his own people. Nothing wrong with that. Plus, I'm not a US citizen, so it is not up to me to like or hate him. Sometimes I even admire him for his persistence and resolve in the face of critical and defaming media coverage, regardless of whether or not he's right... I'm not trying to learn English by listening to him. I was just curious about what he based his "lets-move-the-embassy" decision on. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Well, Sara, he said in that statement what his basis was. Basically, he had looked over the record for the past two decades and had seen no real movement towards peace between the Jews and Palestinians; therefore, he felt that the law should be enforced since nothing has changed in two decades.

Comment: It's all good, @Nick! I will let you know that I down-voted your comment for two reasons, though. First, I don't think you addressed whether or not the sentence in bold is idiomatic or even very correct. I can also figure out what it means from context, but I think it's odd, and I would venture to say I think the usage of "record" is even incorrect—the usage doesn't fit the meaning of the word. Second, I think "fake news of CNN" is subjective, potentially defamatory, and too political for this site.

Comment: I think Trump is talking about the events recorded in history of the last two decades in that part of the world; that he has looked over that "record"; hence, the "record" is in. It may not be the clearest use of the word "record", but I see nothing wrong with it.